# Submit method not recognizing AddWithValue

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to get my submit button to insert data entered into a couple text boxes and a hidden field. Right now, it gives me an error saying that the name "txtComments", "txtName", and "datePosted" do not exist in the current context. I'm relatively certain that I have to create the variable, but how would I make sure they are equal to what's in the respective ASP controls? Here's my code:

```
protected void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=~\App_Data\TravelJoansDB.accdb";
    string cmdstr = "INSERT INTO Comments VALUES (@txtComments, @datePosted, @personName)";

    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
    OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr, con);
    con.Open();
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtComments", txtComments.TextBox);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datePosted", datePosted.DateTime);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@personName", txtName.TextBox);
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

So how do I make sure the variables are set to the asp controls? Which are here:

```
<InsertItemTemplate>
    Name: <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("personName") %>'></asp:TextBox><br />
    Comments:<br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtComments" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("commentText") %>'
                TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="4" Columns="50"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hidTimeDate" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("datePosted") %>' />
    <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                    CommandName="Insert" Text="Submit" OnClick="submitButton_Click" />
</InsertItemTemplate>
```

Comment: inside which control this `InsertItemTemplate` control located?

Comment: an update panel, which is included in a content placeholder because I'm using master pages.

Comment: i mean gridview or listview?

Comment: Ah, it's in a Formview control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code behind:

```
protected void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=~\App_Data\TravelJoansDB.accdb";
    string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database21.accdb;";
    string cmdstr = "INSERT INTO Comments(commentText,datePosted,personName) VALUES (@txtComments, @datePosted, @personName)";
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
    OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr, con);
    TextBox tComments = (TextBox)FormView1.FindControl("txtComments");
    HiddenField tDate = (HiddenField)FormView1.FindControl("hidTimeDate");
    TextBox tName = (TextBox)FormView1.FindControl("txtName");
    con.Open();
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtComments", tComments.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datePosted", DateTime.Now.ToString());
    //com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datePosted", tDate.Value.ToString());
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@personName", tName.Text);
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
protected void FormView1_ItemInserting(object sender, FormViewInsertEventArgs e)
{ 
}
```

**Note: Change your constr!**

ASPX:

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DefaultMode="Insert" 
    oniteminserting="FormView1_ItemInserting">
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        Name: <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" 
    Text='<%# Bind("personName") %>'></asp:TextBox><br />
Comments:<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtComments" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("commentText") %>'
            TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="4" Columns="50"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidTimeDate" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("datePosted") %>' />
<asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                CommandName="Insert" Text="Submit" OnClick="submitButton_Click" />
    </InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

Comment: Using the "DateTime.Now" call, do I need the hidden field in ASP code? Otherwise, it is still telling that txtComments doesn't exist in current context.

Comment: Also, here's a list of namespaces I'm using. I'm sure some of them are extraneous:

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.OleDb;

Comment: My original question had to do with why my AddWithValue and Parameter property are highlighted light blue like in all the examples I see. I assume this is the way it is supposed to look. The other main question is that in the line "com.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtComments.Text);" My "txtComments" is underlined saying it doesn't exist in the current context. Why?

Comment: So when I copy and paste this code, should I change the "OnClick" property of my button to "FormView1_ItemInserting"? I mean, you created a whole different method. My method now has very similar code, but is called "submitButton_clicked" and has "EventArgs e" instead of "FormviewInsertEventArgs"

Comment: I changed EventArgs to FormviewInsertEventArgs and now it gives me the error "No overload for 'submitButton_Click' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler" Looking up the error, it seems like if I'm going to use it for a button, I have to use EventArgs

Comment: Okay, in order for it to work, I also had to add "Response.Redirect("Places.aspx")" to the FormView1_InsertingItem method. But after I did that, it started working perfectly!!!